# C++ Socket communication over wifi between two different machines

Tags: c++, windows-10, wifi

I have two process( written in C++) running in windows 10 surface.  So, I want do a wireless communication from one process to another. I know that socket communication can be used for network communication. My worry is whether it is possible to communicate through wifi between these process in windows 10 or not?

If its is not possible what is possible way of wireless communication

### Update:

Sorry for the confusion. This communication is between processes in two different machine over wifi. I know that a socket communication will do the trick for a wired connection.My doubt is whether this communication is possible over wifi between two windows machines

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. Beween processes or between machines? If it's the same machine, why do you need to go through wifi? Local socket should be okay. Google "interprocess communication" might give you a start.

Comment: Wired or not, a network interface should be all the same for the applications.

Comment: I know about inter process socket communication. this between processes in two different machine over wifi. My doubt is whether this communication is possible over wifi between two windows machines

Comment: Why do you think the transmission medium matters?

Comment: WiFi, fiber, CAT5 cable, or any other medium is irrelevant. As long as a driver for the hardware is installed and working, Windows will set up a network adapter that has the same user-facing interface as any other, and can be used via the published Windows API. The only differences between them *may* be any feature(s) that the particular hardware itself does not support, in which case the API will return an error.

Comment: When using sockets you're usually not restricted to any _physical_ medium. The socket is provided by system calls on your operating system. As far as i remeber they are running on the 'session' layer (layer 5 , OSI-Layers). The physical medium is layer 1. This layer is covered by your operating system and your drivers. The OS provides enough abstraction for you to simply use the sockets no matter what physical medium is used as long as it's available/installed and running.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I can conclude like, socket communication can be used irrespective of the medium. Hardware should supports wireless communication, thats all. Cheers guys!!

Answer (score 2):

wifi is just a communication method, as long as the drivers of both sides of the communication are correctly installed, socket communication can be performed in the same local area network.